# Is it possible multiple exception in an try block in c#?

Tags: c#-4.0

Is it possible to add multiple exception in an try block in c# ?

if possible,please provide with sample code

Thanks,
Santhu

Comment: What do you mean by "add multiple exception"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to use exceptions from specific to more generics in different catch block

```
try {} 
catch(FileNotFoundException fex) {}
catch(IOExceoption iex) {}
catch(Exception ex) {}
finally {}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can provide multiple catch block block for a single try block like this:-

```
   try
   {
        //your code
   }
   catch(ExceptionClass e)
   {
       //code to handle exception
   }
   catch(ExceptionClass2 e)
   {
       //code to handle exception
   }
   catch(ExceptionClass3 e)
   {
       //code to handle exception
   }
```

but you always have to take care of hierarchy of Exception Classes. like for example, ExceptionClass should not be the Super class of ExceptionClass2 and ExceptionClass3.

Comment: Can we do it in try block not in catch?

Comment: you cannot handle Exception in try block but their is a concept of nested try catch. you can specify another try block inside try block but then also you have to provide catch block to handle exception.

Answer (score 1):

Yes

```
try
{
 stuff()
}
catch (Exception1 e1)
{

}
catch (Exception2 e2)
{

}
finally
{

}
```

Comment: is it possible in single try block not in catch block?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
try
{
// Your code
}
catch(an exception)
{
}
catch(a different exception)
{
}
catch(any exception you want)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply...but what i am looking in try block not in catch block

Comment: I don't understand, the purpose of the catch block is to catch the exception from the try block, what is it that you are trying to do? Could you provide any example code, just to demonstrate it?

Comment: this question raised in interview...i told them it is possible in catch level but still they ask me is it possible in try block?

Comment: Not that I know of, I have never seen or heard of being able to do that before, maybe it's just to *catch* you out (pun intended) :)